# Laravel Production Error - Unable to Create Lockable Cache File

Tags: linux, laravel, file-permissions

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I've encountered a perplexing issue with my Laravel API in a production environment, and I'm seeking guidance to resolve it. Some users are reporting the following error related to cache file permissions:

```
"Unable to create lockable file: /var/www/html/storage/framework/cache/data/19/e1/19e1c3ab2b97503139abbc7edb2dc5ceac440775. Please ensure you have permission to create files in this location."
```

Can anyone shed light on the root cause of this error and provide suggestions on how to rectify the cache file permission issue in a Laravel production environment?

Any insights, solutions, or troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

I checked the permissions:
As you can see all the folders are marked with "www-data" permission. The specific folder causing the error is with a "root" permission. I don't know why this is happening

[folder permissions screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxnV5.png)

I've attempted to address this by running php artisan config:cache, but unfortunately, the problem persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

give your storage 775 by the following command in ur server terminal

```
sudo chmod -R 775 storage
```

make sure to give the folder the right permssion of your web server

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data storage
```

Don't forget to restart it

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```